# Check if nullptr in Dart FFI

Tags: dart, null, ffi, nullptr

What would be the best way to check if a pointer is a nullpointer in Dart using FFI?

Current approach is this:

```
ffi.Pointer<Thing> thing = ... // can potentially return null
if(thing == ffi.nullptr) {
 ...
```

But, of course, this gives a "Equality operator `==` invocation with references of unrelated types." warning message.

The API is still quite new, and I am not exactly sure how to approach this. I could also be overthinking this and there's a super simple answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I have yet to try dart:ffi but from the API documentation for == you can see:

> Equality for Pointers only depends on their address

https://api.dart.dev/dev/2.6.0-dev.0.0/dart-ffi/Pointer-class.html

So, what you can do is just to compare the address of the two pointers:

```
ffi.Pointer<Thing> thing = ... // can potentially return null
if(thing.address == ffi.nullptr.address) {
 ...
```

In fact, a nullpointer are just a Pointer which points to the address 0:

```
final Pointer<Void> nullptr = Pointer.fromAddress(0)
```

https://api.dart.dev/dev/2.6.0-dev.0.0/dart-ffi/nullptr.html

Comment: Duh, simple enough solution! If only I knew how to read... Thanks. :)